# how do I remove this faucet?

Tags: faucet

The faucet runs even when the handles are turned off so I wanted to pull these off and see if I could figure out what is going on...

but I have no idea how to get the faucets off. No visible set screws.

The rings above the conical base pop up then the conical base turns about 2 full revolutions then stops. Is it possible these things are just press on?

EDIT: found the set screws, but it did just slide off. With the ring above the conical part moved, and the conical part screwed all the way down, a small set screw was revealed!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked for Allen/set screws?

Comment: Yep, as I mention in the post, there are no visible set screws that I can see.

Comment: Figured it out, see edit to original post.